# serialport in Electron forge (+webpack) renderer fails to load bindings?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, node-serialport

I'm having an issue getting the serialport package to work in Electron Forge + Webpack in the renderer:

Using electron forge CLI, I made a brand new project:

```
npm init electron-app@latest my-new-app -- --template=webpack
```

I then installed the latest serialport package:

```
npm install serialport
```

I want to use serialport in the renderer so I import it into renderer.js:

```
import { SerialPort } from "serialport";
```

Running this however gives me a bunch of import errors:

[image]

## What I've tried

- I tried moving this import into the preload.js. This gives a different error about not having a prebuilt version:

> Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=110 uv=1 libc=glibc node=16.17.1 electron=22.0.0 webpack=true

- Tried using electron-rebuild to rebuild serialport `electron-rebuild -f -w serialport`
- I tried enabling `nodeIntegration: true`

This is for an internal development testing tool so security of enabling things that are generally not suggested is okay with me if that is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with a `No native build was found for platform` error message when importing `serialport` in Electron's main process. I was using `electron-forge` to build my distributable. I also tried using `electron-rebuild` manually, to no avail.

I spent a couple of days digging through Stack Overflow posts and GitHub issues and did some experiments. In the end it looks like the issue is caused by `electron-rebuild` not detecting `serialport`'s native node modules on certain platforms. In my case, `electron-rebuild` was rebuilding the `serialport` native node modules on my M1 MacBook Pro (arm64), but wasn't rebuilding these modules on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (armv7l).

What fixed it for me in the end (credit to the [this](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/issues/2463#issuecomment-1227334940) GitHub comment) is running the following commands before Electron's packaging step:

```
rm --recursive node_modules/@serialport
npm install --no-save --build-from-source serialport@10.4.0
```

This will first delete all the contents of your `node_modules/@serialport` folder, which contains prebuilt native node modules for several platforms in the `bindings-cpp` package. Next, we build `serialport`'s native node modules from scratch, so that we (hopefully) end up with a native node module that matches our current platform.

Make sure the version of `serialport` used in the above command matches the version you depend on!